# Finding Patient Encounters with Different Encounter IDs but Matching or Similar Dates

Tags: sas

I am working with patient encounter data where I have patient IDs and encounter IDs. The problem is that there are instances where the one patient visit will have two different encounter IDs that should actually be the same.  The way to fix this would be to search for matching or similar dates in the contact date and ordering  date columns.  I will need to create a variable that flags matching or similar dates, where I can make a new encounter ID that matches.

What I have:

| PATIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_ID | CONTACT_DATE | ORDERING_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 476234AAA | 05JUL2017 | . |
| ABC123 | 021389AAA | . | 21MAY2019 |
| ABC123 | 091828AAA | 21MAY2019 | . |
| ABC123 | 021654AAA | . | 24MAY2019 |

What I need: Where Flag = 1 means there are matching dates in the contact date and ordering date columns & Flag = 2 means there are similar dates in the contact date and ordering date columns

| PATIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_ID | CONTACT_DATE | ORDERING_DATE | FLAG | NEW_ENCOUNTER_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 476234AAA | 05JUL2017 | . | 0 |  |
| ABC123 | 021389AAA | . | 21MAY2019 | 1 | 021389BBB |
| ABC123 | 091828AAA | 21MAY2019 | . | 1 | 021389BBB |
| ABC123 | 021654AAA | . | 24MAY2019 | 2 |  |

Comment: Why do you think the two different encounter ids is a problem?  A patient could be seen by any number of different care providers in a single day.

Comment: I need to perform an analysis in which encounters (each patient can have several) are the denominator for the study outcome . The ordering date was derived from a separate table but the problem is that it should have the same encounter id as the office visit its associated with. In these cases, the lab order (ordering date) is actually related to the office encounter but for some reason it has been showing up with a different encounter ID. Therefore, we need to adjust for these cases.

Comment: So you want to link the lab encounter with the office encounter.  Are you sure the associated lab visit will always be on the same day as the office visit?

Comment: Yes, the lab order (with a difference encounter ID) is from the same encounter. For some reason, sometimes lab orders result in different encounter IDs because it ends up in a difference table.